# How retrieve related Entity ID in CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm triying to get PriceLevelId value from a Product entity. I used a ColumSet to retrieve product value but PriceLevelId is stored in a related Entity and I'm not able to retrieve this ID value.

Can anyone some tip gimme me? (I'm a new developer in CRM area)

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: Could you add a code example to show how you are trying to retrieve the ID value ?

Comment: Which PriceLevelId are you looking for ? Product <-> Price List is a N:N relationship which goes through Price List Items (i.e. you can relate a product to more than one Price List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough but if you want to get the priceLevel entity from c# code in plugin, You can get it like below:

```C#
// I am assuming you already have 'priceId' 
var price = (from p in _context<new_priceEntity>CreateQuery()
             where p.id = priceId
             select p).FirstOrDefault();

//Price level Id is:
var priceLevelId = price.new_priceLevelId.Id;

// get Price value
var priceLevel = (from p in _context<new_priceLevelEntity>CreateQuery()
                  where p.id = priceLevelId 
                  select p).FirstOrDefault();
```